# Неисчезающая ошибка pyowm

Tags: python, openweathermap, weather, pyowm

Я пытался сделать программу для показа погоды, но выходит ошибка. Я полностью скопировал код(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fp5-XQFr_nk), но ошибка pyowm всё ещё остаётся.

```
    import pyowm

    owm = pyowm.OWM('19af304f37703415ecd99f5788efb1bb')

    place = input('В каком городе/стране?: ')

    observation = owm.weather_at_place(place)
    w = observation.get_weather()

    print(w)
```

Ошибка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Так изменил твой код и у меня работает

```
from pyowm import OWM

owm = OWM('Свой API')
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
place = input('В каком городе/стране?: ')

observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.weather

print(w)
```